# Trying to create a new project -> eclipse says project already exists when in fact there are no projects (no project is seen in Explorer)

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-kepler

I am a newbie to Eclipse.

I use Eclipse Kepler.

I deleted all work spaces (no .metadata...).

Started eclipse from scratch and created a new workspace.

Then I am trying to create a new PyDev project. When I point the wizard to the project folder location: /qwerty/regression, it says the following:

.project found in: /qwerty/regression (use the Import Project wizard instead).

Please assist. P L E A S E.

There are no filters applied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you have a hidden file called .project from a previous trial at /qwerty/regression. Either remove it or import the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lrnzcig comment above is the correct answer.